# Calculate a return for a period of time using SAS

Tags: sas

My data is a set of columns as follows:

```
gvkey   date        div    price
1166    19970429    0   25.6
1166    19970502    0   26
1166    19970505    0   25.9
1166    19970506    0   22.1
1166    19970507    0   19
1166    19970509    0   20.4
1166    19970512    0   21.4
1166    19970513    0   21.7
1166    19970514    0   21.7
1166    19970515    0   21.1
1166    19970516    0   21.5
1166    19970520    0   21
1166    19970521    0   21.8
1166    19970522    0   22.2
1166    19970523    0   22.7
1166    19970526    0   23.9
1166    19970527    0   24
1166    19970528    0   24.2
1166    19970529    0   24.3
1166    19970530    0   23.7
```

In excel, I was able to calculate the return for the month of May just by adding a column that calculated the daily rtn ((price + div)/lag price)). Then I add a column of one plus rtn which multiplies today's daily rtn by the prior row one plus value.  Of course, for the first day of the period, the one plus rtn value = daily rtn.

In excel I calculated 0.925781 as the one plus rtn for May 30th and -0.07422 as the rtn for that month. How can I make SAS do this for me? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data want;
set have;
format rtn crtn percent12.4;
retain crtn 1;
rtn = (price + div)/lag(price) - 1;
crtn = (1 + crtn) * (1 + sum(rtn,0)) - 1;
run;
```

This calculates return `rtn` as you describe.

We create a cumulative return `crtn` with a starting value of 1.  `RETAIN` tells SAS to keep the value of this variable between rows.  So we then update it on each row.

`sum(rtn,0)` = `rtn + 0`.  On the first row, RTN will be null, but the `SUM()` function will ignore that null and return 0.

**EDIT:** Ask in comments about having the cumulative return reset each year.  This assumes a variable `fyear` is on the data set and the data continue to be sorted in the correct order.

```
data want;
set have;

by fyear;

format rtn crtn percent12.4;
retain crtn 1;

if first.fyear then do; /*Check for the start of a new BY group*/
    crtn = 1;
end;

rtn = (price + div)/lag(price) - 1;
crtn = (1 + crtn) * (1 + sum(rtn,0)) - 1;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe we're on the right track, but my numbers are not matching up after the first row.  In excel, the rtn for may 2nd is 0.015625 (this agrees with my sas output). but then the rtn for may 5th in excel is 0.011719 (sas shows -0.3846). and by the end of the month my excel calculation is -0.07422.

Comment: my excel calculations   
date daily rtn 1+rtn subt 1 
19970429    
19970502 1.015625 1.015625 0.015625 
19970505 0.996153846 1.01171875 0.01171875 
19970506 0.853281853 0.86328125 -0.13671875 
19970507 0.859728507 0.7421875 -0.2578125 
...
 
19970529 1.004132231 0.94921875 -0.05078125 
19970530 0.975308642 0.92578125 -0.07421875 return for May of 1997 = -0.0742, according to excel

Comment: Ahhh! I believe my starting point should be 'crtn 0' instead of 'crtn 1'.  Now it looks correct.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Now that this little chunk of code works to calculate cumulative rtns, how can I get it to stop and restart at the end of a period? can it be put into a macro and run by year? if I can insert a year variable into this dataset, that is.  I'm not sure how to write the macro.

Comment: add a year variable to the data set and use a BY group.  At the first record of the BY group, reset the value for crtn.  Please upvote the answer if it helps.

Comment: how do I 'up vote'? when I tried to use the up arrow, it implied that I didn't have enough history on this site

Comment: I've added a year variable (fyear).  I'm not sure where to put the "by fyear" statement or how to get it to reset the value for crtn with each change in fyear.  Can you help with this?data want;
set have;
format rtn crtn percent12.4;
by fyear;     /*is this the correct spot? how to get crtn to reset?*/               retain crtn 0;
rtn = (price + div)/lag(price) - 1;
crtn = (1 + crtn) * (1 + sum(rtn,0)) - 1;
run;

Comment: I updated the code to show you how to use the `by` statement and how to check for the start of a `by` group.

Comment: Thank you. This works for running by fyear.  But now I need to run it by company identifier (gvkey) and fyear.  So that I will have annual cumulative returns by company.  I modified the code to say 'by gvkey fyear' but this is not working.  And tried to modify the do loop to recognize the change from company.  My data is sorted by gvkey and fyear.